# Cancelable backgroundworker but don't violate SRP

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, single-responsibility-principle

Having a long running measurement inside a `backgroundworker`. The measurement should **not** know that it is running in another thread because of `SRP`([Single reponsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Let's consider this for example:

```
void MeasurementWorker(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   Measurement measurement = new Measurement();
   measurement.Execute();
}
```

How to allow a cancellation of the measurement such a pattern?

Edit: `Measurement.Execute` is now to long running measurement method which should be cancelable but it should the `SRP` of the measurement should not be violated with threading context. For example to do some testing without a threading context.

Comment: Why don't you use the Task Processing Library for this purpose? It has builtin support for cancellation using the CancellationTokenSource class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your measurement processing to be cancellable you must make it aware of some sort of cancellation flag. Alternative is to cancel it (abort) in an non-compliant way but that is highly discouraged because you could stop your processing in a middle of something important and without giving it a chance to clean up or free resources.

Instead of `BackgroundWorker` you could use [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and then code could look like this:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                      {
                                          Measurement measurement = new Measurement();
                                          measurement.Execute(cts.Token);
                                      }, 
                                      cts.Token, 
                                      TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
                                      TaskScheduler.Default);
```

where `Execute` might look something like this:

```
public void Execute(CancellationToken ct)
{
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    while (true)
    {
        // processing
        // ...

        // need to cancel?
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

To cancel call this in main thread:

```
cts.Cancel();
```

You will get `TaskCancelledException` but that is expected.

Alternatively, if you do not want exception use the following version of `Execute`. It is not strictly per TPL guidelines but it will work fine if you do not use conditional [continuations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405.aspx).

```
public void Execute(CancellationToken ct)
{
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        return;

    while (true)
    {
        // processing
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in my comments I would use the TPL for this problem. Here is a solution that allows cancellation without violating the SRP:

Wrap .NET Framework BackgroundWorker in your own class that implements and interface ICancellable as follows:

```
public interface ICancellable
{
    bool CancellationPending {get;}
}

public class BackgroundWorkerWrapper : ICancellable
{
    private BackgroundWorker _realWorker;

    public BackgroundWorkerWrapper(BackgroundWorker realWorker)
    {
        _realWorker = realWorker;
    }

    public bool CancellationPending 
    {
        get { return _realWorker.CancellationPending; }
    }
}
```

In your DoWork handler do the following:

```
void MeasurementWorker(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    ICancellable cancellable = new BackgroundWorkerWrapper(worker);
    Measurement lastMeasurement = new Measurement();
    lastMeasurement.Execute(cancellable);
}
```

Now in your Measurement you can check if cancel was requested in a clean way using the CancellationPending Property.

What you say?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask you some questions? How is the cancellation provided in this example? Let's consider the example that the measurement is running and I want to cancel it. Doesn't the Execute method need a CancellationToken to geht out? What does your Stop method intends to do?

Comment: To request cancellation from a BackgroundWorker you should call the CancelAsync method. In the DoWork handler you should periodically check the CancellationPending property as explained on MSDN. I edited my code to reflect this. CancellationToken is relevant if you use TPL.

Comment: Ahh now I get or let's say there is some misinterpretation of my problem. `Measurement.Execute()` is the long running method, which only gets called one time - this is the method I want to cancel.

Comment: @Razer - so please refine your question so I will be able to help.

Comment: @Razer If you can't edit the implementation of the method to periodically check for cancellation then see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx) on the subject.